# Express.js - routes wont work if they have multiple / - 404 error

Tags: express

GET /user/me - sends back 404 (resource not found)

If I change the second '/' to a '_' (i.e GET users_me), then it works.

I have two questions:

1) How to fix it so I can use 'GET /user/me'?

2) It works with an underscore so is there any advantage to using the slash vs. the underscore?

///////////Code

```
require('./config/config');

const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

//const multer = require('multer');
//const router = express.Router();
var renameKeys = require('rename-keys');

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');

//var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
var {User} = require('./models/user');
var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');

var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.json());




// GET users/me

app.get('/users_me', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});



// POST /users -- signing up a new user [how will this handle logging in instead of signing up?]
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
  var user = new User(body);
  user.save().then(() => {
    return user.generateAuthToken();
  }).then((token) => {
    res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  })
});



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started up at port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = {app};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

Just change

```
app.get('/users_me', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

to

```
app.get('/users/:me', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

Then make a Get request:

```
somehost:someport/users/myusername
```

Second question:

Routing works just like a  file-system:

```
/path/subpath/
```

So you can't use an underscore to substitute a slash '/'

**INFO**: You could pass the id or name (depends on your logic) of the user in the URL of your GET-request:

GET request (in this case to localhost with port 3000):

```
localhost:3000/users/getuserbyid/20
```

route:

```
 router.get('/getuserbyid/:id', .....
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thanks! I initially did '/users/me' but it didn't work, so I changed it to the underscore. What you have suggested is what I saw elsewhere but it wont work for me.

Comment: But I still don't know how to get it to work with '/users/me'?  I initially tried it but then when it didn't work, I used '/users_me'.

Comment: You should have different routes for login and registration, i.E.: 

router.post('users/login',...)
router.post('users/register',...)
etc..
And it's also recommendable to put routes in different files in a '/routes' folder , especially if you have auth-logic with token generation and guards to prevent unauthorized acccess to certain routes (i.E. admin components) - otherwise your app.js becomes a big mess ;)

Comment: I personally use **postman** to test my routes - which i can definitly recommend to you! Regarding your question in the comments - can you provide the request you made? And don't forget to recompile the codechanges - or use **nodemon** ;)

Comment: did you try **router.get('/users/:someusername', ...)** ?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out. I think your last comments suggests you may have know what was wrong. I had a get('user/:id') route. I comment that out and it solved the problem. As I move on in this online course, I will likely find out what went wrong.